# rename files in current folder (mandatory : for mv cut commands)

Tags: shell

I would like to rename all the .jpg files in the current folder in .jpeg.
I have seen a lot of solutions with the rename command but in my book they say I can do it with ls,mv and cut. I know I can use pipe, but I don't know in which order I could do it.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do it with `ls` and `mv` and a loop (I only see one place you might use `cut` and that's not a good use for `cut`) but you don't *want* to. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for details on why.

Using `mv` and a loop is fine. Using `ls` to drive the loop is not.

```
for file in ./*.jpg; do
    mv -v "$file" "${file%.jpg}.jpeg"
done
```

Comment: +1 for doing it right regardless. Also, `mv -v --` or `./*.jpg` just in case